# ng-show stops working within success callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I keep my ng-show outside of a function, then it does the task perfectly but if I keep it inside a success function of an HTTP post method, it doesn't do anything.

I would like to trigger my ng-show right after the post method is successful, but can't get through.

my Angular code:

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, 

$http) {
  $scope.data = {
    div1: false,
    div2: false
  };

  $scope.showText = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/'
    }).success(
      function(response) {
        $scope.data.div1 = true;
      },
      function(response) {
        var fail_status = response.status;
        console.log('test ' + fail_status);
      }
    );
  };
});
```

my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-show="data.div1">div 1</div>
      <div ng-show="data.div2">div 2</div>
      <input type="button" ng-click="showText();" value="click me" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of angular are using?

Comment: the CDN of angular that i've included at the bottom of the page is angular 1.0.7

Comment: Its working properly. I have test it